# AlarmManager - Creating multiple repeating alarm triggers on alarm creation, and

Tags: android, alarmmanager

I'm creating alarms in a for loop. Every time I create, delete, or update a Reminder in my app, I rerun scheduleAlarms() so that it recreates the alarms according to the new records. This seems to work well when I create a Reminder, but when I delete one, the alarm is still there. Maybe someone can help me figure out why my alarm isn't removed when I run scheduleAlarms() after removing the respective reminder from the list:

```
public static void scheduleAlarms(Context context) {

    AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager)context.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);

    // Get all reminders from db and create alarms for them.
    ArrayList<Reminder> reminderList = (ArrayList<Reminder>)DbManager.getInstance().getAllReminders();

    for(Reminder reminder: reminderList) {

        Intent reminderServiceIntent = new Intent(context, ReminderService.class);
        reminderServiceIntent.putExtra(Constants.reminderBundleKey, reminder.getId());

        // Create unique pendingIntent for each reminder, request code is reminderId
        PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getService(context,reminder.getId(),reminderServiceIntent, 0);

        // Cancel the alarm before rescheduling
        try {
            alarmManager.cancel(pendingIntent);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e("rx", "PollReceiver: " + e.toString());
        }

        Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
        calendar.setTimeInMillis(System.currentTimeMillis());
        calendar.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, reminder.getHour());
        calendar.set(Calendar.MINUTE,reminder.getMinute());

        alarmManager.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, calendar.getTimeInMillis(),
            AlarmManager.INTERVAL_DAY, pendingIntent);

    }

}
```

/** Update **/
So instead of rescheduling everything after every update, I just broke the Receiver into a couple of methods:

```
public static void scheduleAlarm(Context context, Reminder reminder) {

        AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager)context.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);

        Intent reminderServiceIntent = new Intent(context, ReminderService.class);
        reminderServiceIntent.putExtra(Constants.reminderBundleKey, reminder.getId());

        // Create unique pendingIntent for each reminder, request code is reminderId
        PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getService(context,reminder.getId(),reminderServiceIntent, 0);

        Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
        calendar.setTimeInMillis(System.currentTimeMillis());
        calendar.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, reminder.getHour());
        calendar.set(Calendar.MINUTE,reminder.getMinute());

        alarmManager.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, calendar.getTimeInMillis(),
                AlarmManager.INTERVAL_DAY, pendingIntent);

    }

    public static void cancelAlarm(Context context, Reminder reminder) {

        AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager)context.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);

            Intent reminderServiceIntent = new Intent(context, ReminderService.class);
            PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getService(context,reminder.getId(),reminderServiceIntent, 0);

            try {
                alarmManager.cancel(pendingIntent);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                Log.e("rx", "PollReceiver: " + e.toString());
            }
    }
```

Comment: even if You cancel the alarm, You create a new one at the end. This doesn´t work. You have to cancel the alarm in it´s own method, so that You can cancel it if You want.

Comment: Ok, yeah I see now, feel free to put this in an answer and I'll give you credit. Also, one more question. It's creating and deleting fine now, but it looks like the alarm also fires at the exact moment of creation for each record in the array list (in addition to setting the alarm correctly). Any idea why?

Comment: Yes, thanks, I will put it as answer if we have fixed Your problem with the alarm. First, You don´t need to set calendar.setTimeInMillis, because the calendar has the current time when it is created. I suggest You to make a log to see what reminder.getHour() and reminder.getMinute() returns. Also, check if this what is returned is in the past..maybe here is the problem.